# How would I model a database with entities that have a varying number of attributes?

Tags: database, modeling, diagram, erd

I'm designing a database that I plan on using to track certain things in a video game. I have the schema done for the most part, but I'm having trouble figuring out how I should structure this last part.

Diagram that I have so far (Apologies on any errors, I'm still learning):[image: ERD diagram]

The database is based on the following entities:

- A "**node**" can output either a single item, or a single fluid, depending on the node type.
- An "**item**" or a "**fluid**" can be outputted by zero or many nodes.
- A "**building**" can process zero or many "recipes".
- A "**recipe**" can be processed by one (mandatory) or many "buildings".
  A "recipe" can produce zero or many "item" or "fluid", and takes zero or many "item" or "fluid" as inputs.
  A "recipe" requires at least one "item" or "fluid" output (I was unsure how to represent this in my diagram), but does not require an input (eg. a building that outputs an item/fluid using only energy).

Some example buildings that have different "recipe" structures:
[image: Example with construcor assembler and refinery]

So as you can see, each building that produces a recipe can have varying inputs/outputs. My question is a out how to model this in a way that helps implementing the resulting database.

My initial idea is to create separate entities for each recipe type, i.e. one for recipes with one item input and one item output, another for recipes with 2 item inputs 1 item output, etc., but this obviously seems incredibly inefficient.

My next idea would be to create an entity that contains all the inputs(items or fluids), another that contains all the outputs(items or fluids), and then link those entities to a corresponding recipe but again this seems inefficient since I would need multiple of these entities and they would all have similar structure/attributes.

Is there a way to make these entities have varying number of attributes depending on the recipe in question? If not, what would be the way to solve this (I'm all out of further ideas).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance and polymorphism here.
It's the most easy way to go, if you are familiar with them, of course.

You can use the Decorator design pattern on your base model, you can have a class hierarchy with some additional attributes and methods if they need to.

You can use the Composite design pattern here too, depending how you want to structure the whole thing.

Factory has a meaningfull responsability in source code : it's building something. Input has too : an input is related to any screen|keyboard|voice|video|sensor. So choose accordingly your entities names to write clear source code for you and your dev peers, if any.

Answer (score 0):

To finish your your diagram and get it right, a **second relationship**, `input`,  is needed between `recipe` and `item`, as well as `recipe` and `fluid` because your diagram only models `output` and tells nothing about `input` (the fact that an `input` is not required in some cases does not mean that no `input` is required in general).

The next challenge is to get cardinality right:

- Currently, your diagram says that a `recipe` may have no output `item` and no output `fluid`. It is very difficult in this model to express that a recipe must have at least one output.
- But a lot of complexity in this design comes from "*item or fluid*", whereas both look extremely similar.

You could **simplify**,  by using an entity called `product` that would replace and combine the fluid and the item. Its attributes would be  `product_id`, `product_name`, and  `product_type`  (e.g. 'F' for fluid, 'I' for item). This technique is called [single table inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance).  You can then have the right participation, simply replacing the `o` with `|` on the product side of the outpout relationship to say "*there must be at least one*".

Where I am puzzled, is the different kind of buildings: in your examples, the buildings look like specific instances of recipe, except that you do not have quantity (rate?) in your recipe, and recipe usually have quantities.  To get it right, you need to transform both the `output` and `input` many-to-manly relationships into [associative entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). While UML and Chen's ERD notation provide a simple way to deal with this,  your Crow's foot notation,  requires to break the relationship in 2, inserting a table that has a `product_id`, a `recipe_id`, and a `quantity` inbetween.  This technique in the RDBMS design is called [association table](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html).

According to my understanding, the relation ship of a building with the recipe it manages, allows to find out all you need to know by deriving it from all the relevant recipes.